# can i mix NHibernate updates with direct SQL in the same transaction

Tags: nhibernate

I'm wondering if it is possible to do direct SQL updates of my own in the same transaction as NHibernate is using to update my persistent objects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with `ITransaction.Enlist(IDbCommand)`.

See [this blog post](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshua_lockwood/archive/2007/04/10/how-to-enlist-ado-commands-into-an-nhibernate-transaction.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm currently investigating how to get round a problem with a table that has no primary key (in another post) but this could be my lifeline if I can't find a better approach